# Android Metadata

Tags: android, xml, version, manifest

Quick question. Where would the proper place be to store some metadata in my Android app that won't get overwritten with an update from the Market? I want to store an offline database version number, and compare it to an online database number, but i'm afraid if I store it in a meta-data tag in the Manifest, it'll get overwritten. On the iPhone version of the app, I just made a custom plist file, and used that. Is there a comparable way for Android to work with custom files like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) are the place for that.